# Dymola integration with R

Tags: r, dymola

Someone has script examples for integrating R and Dymola,
I want to perform Monte Carlo Simulations in a Dymola model

the main idea will be performing an uncertainty analysis regarding the integration of renewables into the system.

we have a calibrated model of a building which is heated by a gas fired boiler, and we are going to implement a solar collector and a biomass gas fired boiler and check the probability of x% of the energy demand to be covered by the integrating y% of renewables

But I am struggling to learn how I can make R sample, call my model and analyse the results

I do not have experience with R

Can anyone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with R but Dymola offers the following possibilities to remote control it:

- Python
- Java (Script)
- DDE e.g. from MATLAB
- Some others that don't seem relevant for this case (can be found in Dymola Manual 2 Section 6)

There is no possibility to call it directly from R as far as I know. What you can do as well is call `dymosim.exe` directly and modify the `dsin.txt` to get your parameters in the model.

From my experience I would tend to use the Python interface. Probably a good way could be to combine R and Python as presented here: https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/rpy

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the possibilities listed by [Markus Andres](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46641393/8725275), there is another method which is used quite often:

- Calling the `Dymola.exe` the path to a .mos script as first argument.
  Dymola will start up and immediately execute the .mos script.

A minimal .mos script would be:

```
openModel("<path-to-model>/MyModel.mo")
simulateModel("MyModel")
Modelica.Utilities.System.exit()
```

Note that you can not interact with Dymola using this method, so the `exit()` call is crucial. If the `exit()` call is not reached for whatever reason, the Dymola.exe will continue to run as idle process and you have to kill the process from R.

The Dymola User Manual Volume 1 also mentions this feature briefly in the section *Parameter studies by running Dymola a number of time in “batch mode”* and gives some hints how to log messages and set the result file names.